# Pusher.subscribe() is not a function from the server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pusher, pusher-js

I'm trying to use pusher.subscribe() on the server side, but Pusher is only for client side.

I found this: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-node

Which allows us to set up a pusher for the server side. However, the readme is outdated and I can't set it up.

Running this command

`npm install pusher --prefix cloud/modules`

Only creates: cloud/modules/etc and cloud/modules/node_modules.

This means I cant run

`$ cd cloud/modules/pusher`

`$ npm run parse-build`

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `cd cloud/modules/node_modules/pusher` and then `npm run parse-build` it will create build for Parse cloud

> 'Creating build for Parse Cloud.' && webpack --config=./parse.webpack.js Creating build for Parse Cloud. sh: webpack: command not found

Install webpack using `npm install -g webpack` globally or locally to install webpack local for the project `npm install -D` to install all dev dependencies in your `cd cloud/modules/node_modules/pusher` directory.It is recommended to install webpack locally so that you need not to stick to a particular version for different projects.

Comment: Cant use that: I get : 

echo 'Creating build for Parse Cloud.' && webpack --config=./parse.webpack.js

Creating build for Parse Cloud.
sh: webpack: command not found

Comment: it can be used from terminal if installed globally `npm uninstall -g webpack` and then try installing it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't subscribe with `Pusher` you can only **trigger** and some other functions

if you want to subscribe from the server side(nodejs e.t.c)

use `pusher-js`

`npm i pusher-js` or `yarn add pusher-js`